# Power rating of dual output isolated DC/DC converter

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter, isolation

I would like to use an isolated DC/DC converter SIP to generate 19 V from a 12 V input voltage for a gate drive application with approximately 1.2 W output power required. The isolation voltage should be 5.2 kV.

Looking at the [Murata's DCDC catalog](https://power.murata.com/pub/data/power/cd-dcdc_pdb1.pdf) there seems to be no obvious solution. Choosing a slightly higher output voltage and using an additional linear regulator would be an option. For example, the [MEJ2D1212SC](https://datasheet.ciiva.com/6220/mej2-6220638.pdf?src-supplier=Digi-Key) could be used to generate +-12 V to generate 24 V essentially. However, this will cause quite some additional (possibly unnecessary) power dissipation in the linear regulator.

The actual question is regarding the [MGJ2D121505SC](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/281/kdc_mgj2-318966.pdf) with output voltages of +15 V and -5 V. Using this as a 20 V supply would be favorable. However, the specified output currents are relatively low compared to the 2 W power specification as can be seen here:

[image]

Is the power rating just a general approximation and the output currents are the meaningful data? When using this as a 20 V source, would I be limited to the 40 mA of "Output Current 2"?

Comment: Assuming you can stack them in the way you want, since the same current would flow through both outputs you'd take the lower current rating.  Below that I see they have a 20V 80mA module which amounts to 1.6W.

Comment: @KH Good point. I suspect not using one of the outputs will be unproblematic.

Comment: What gate do you need 19 volts to drive?  Best drive voltage is usually less than absolute maximum.  On the datasheet there should be a graph to see if you really need 19v or if 15 or 20 are ok.

Comment: 5.2kV is very a very high isolation voltage. Is it 5.2kV DC or 1sec pulse? Or AC? 

Your requirement suggests a custom power supply with some serious transformer- which is pain in a neck. If you can somehow relax the isolation requirement and live with Muata or Recom or Traco (or something else) that would be much easier. Maybe you could use two supplies in series

Comment: @KH I will use 19 V, together with a zener diode circuit, to drive SiC MOSFETs with recommended drive voltages of +15V / -4V. I would like to stay as close as possible to the recommendation to minimize losses and stay away from maximum ratings.

Comment: Ok then the 20v supply is out because of where you need your mid point.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum The working voltage applied to the isolation barrier will be a lot lower, switching between approximately 0V and 450V. However, safety is a concern and I would rather use a 5.2kV isolation rated Murata (or possibly other manufacturer) than lower rated ones. Murata also mentions much lower working voltages in the datasheets.

Comment: @KH I could use a linear regulator to get 19V from 20V, then use a 4V zener diode to get 15V and -4V. This is how I previously intended it, but with 24V input which leads to a good amount of power dissipation in the linear regulator. So the 20V supply should be a good option.

Comment: I'm not sure how much current the tener will have to pass to hold those offsets bit I hope it works for you.

Comment: @LarsHankeln one thing i saw very common in servo drives- a flyback supply (mains to DC) that has a transformer with a dozen of secondary outputs. all isolated and all rated to high voltage. Just keep in mind, such solutions are possible, though it's not easy to make a transformer. Wurth (medcom) can probably help. Overall it's a bit more complex, but cheaper solution.